# MYSQL - Query, Buscar últimos valores de um banco de dados baseado no dia e na hora do registro com um inner join

Tags: mysql, group-by, where, inner-join

boa tarde...
Preciso de uma ajuda dos nobres programadores deste forum para resolver um pequeno bug (já adianto que não sou programador, sou curioso). Tenho 2 bancos de dados, o primeiro banco é dinâmico, ele recebe novos dados a cada 1 minuto (ou seja a cada 1 minuto 283 novas linhas entram no banco de dados) e um segundo  banco de dados fixo com 203 linhas (esse banco é estático, não será atualizado).

[image: Esse é o banco de dados fixo, a primeira coluna (Asset) sempre vai existir no banco dinâmico]

[image: Esse é o banco de dados dinâmico, que atualiza a cada 1 minuto. a coluna SYMBOL tem os mesmos itens da Asset, existe a possibilidade de ter vários ativos duplicados, por isso temos que buscar sempre o ultimo baseado no tempo (coluna DATEOK)]

Continuando, eu fiz uma query que faz o inner join, porém ela está buscando os dados errados do banco de dados, ela mostra algumas colunas certas, mas a parte que vem do banco de dados dinâmico não está correta, está vindo valores de 2 dias atrás, sendo que deveria retornar somente o ultimo registro baseado no tempo e correspondente a coluna Asset do banco fixo, ou seja, a consulta sempre terá 203 linhas...

Essa é a query que estou utilizando:

[image: Demonstração da query]

```
select a.Asset, a.FM, a.BANDASUP1, a.BANDAINF1, a.BANDASUP2, a.BANDAINF2, a.RL, a.FORCE, a.IBOV, a.ST, b.SYMBOL,b.DATE, b.TIME, b.LAST, b.VOLUME, b.PROJECTED_VOLUME, b.TRUE_RANGE, b.VWAP, b.DATETIME
from rtd.bdfixoteste2 as a
inner join (select max(DATEOK) as DATETIME, SYMBOL, DATE, LAST, TIME,  VOLUME, PROJECTED_VOLUME, TRUE_RANGE, VWAP
   from rtd.profitchart_01m_cleanf
   WHERE DATEOK >= CURDATE() 
      group by LAST
   ) as b
   On (b.SYMBOL = a.Asset) ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
```

Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?
Esclarecendo melhor, eu queria que esssa query retornasse sempre os ultimos registros do banco de dados dinâmico baseado na coluna Asset.

Para completar, a primeira imagem é referente a tabela fixa (bdfixoteste2) e a segunda imagem é referente a tabela dinâmico (profitchart_01m_cleanf) ambos estão dentro do banco de dados rtd.

Comment: Em seu subselect você está fazendo um GROUP BY apenas pelo campo LAST quando deveria fazer por todos os campos que não estão em alguma função de agregação, no caso deveria ser: GROUP BY SYMBOL, DATE, LAST, TIME,  VOLUME, PROJECTED_VOLUME, TRUE_RANGE, VWAP. Poderia omitir algum campo desde que exista uma dependência funcional do campo omitido para algum dos campos da cláusula GROUP BY. Não tenho certeza de que é o que deseja, talvez seja necessário mais de um subselect.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, adicionei essa condição no group by porém, agora, está retornando 36328 linhas, onde deveria vir somente os 203 registros que estão no banco fixo.

Comment: Fica meio difícil de opinar sem conhecer o sifnificado dos campos.Talvez os campos de seu subselect devam se restringir a `max(DATEOK) as DATETIME, SYMBOL`. e com `GROUP BY SYMBOL`.

Comment: Arrumei uma solução, porém agora estou com um erro de ambiguidade (Error Code: 1052. Column 'SYMBOL' in field list is ambiguous
) de colunas, o que será que está errado agora? SELECT r.* FROM

rtd.profitchart_01m_cleanf r

                INNER JOIN (SELECT SYMBOL, DATE, MAX(TIME) FROM rtd.profitchart_01m_cleanf t

                INNER JOIN (SELECT SYMBOL, MAX(DATE) FROM rtd.profitchart_01m_cleanf GROUP BY SYMBOL) d ON d.SYMBOL = t.SYMBOL AND d.DATE = t.DATE

                GROUP BY t.SYMBOL, t.DATE) f ON f.SYMBOL = r.SYMBOL AND f.DATE = r.DATE AND f.TIME = r.TIME